# How to get Sum of all possible values from a collection of [Any] array

Tags: ios, swift, higher-order-functions

```
let array = [1,5,6,"50","Hi",54] as [Any]
```

I am having an array like this need sum of every possible values from this collection
Using Higher order function

Comment: I'm not sure I follow -- what would the expected result be in the case of your example?

Comment: It must be addition of (50+54+6+5+1) = 116

Comment: So `String` values that can be converted to `Int`s should be, but the ones that can't (ie `Hi`) are dropped? But it's `Any`, not just `String` and `Int`, so are there any other type that must be converted to an Int?

Comment: I need Sum of every possible values inside collection So that "Hi" string can be dropped

Comment: You are supposed to show your own attempt and not just excepting us to do all the job.

Comment: True 
From next time will follow this practice
Thanks for your suggesstion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for `Int`s and `String`s that can be converted to an `Int`. It drops strings that can't be converted and ignores all other types.

```
let result = array.reduce(into: 0) { partialResult, item in
    switch item {
    case let someInt as Int:
        partialResult += someInt
    case let someString as String:
        if let intValue = Int(someString) {
            partialResult += intValue
        }
    default:
        break
    }
}
```